# Which firewall ports need to be opened up between ADFS and AD servers?

Tags: windows, azure, networking, active-directory, adfs

I have 2 ADFS servers in one Azure subnet and 2 AD Servers in another subnet. What NSG rules do I need to add to incoming and outgoing for the ADFS and AD Subnets?

Also there are ADFS proxy servers which will talk to the ADFS Servers. Which ports need to be opened for ADFS Proxy Servers to ADFS Servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AD FS Network requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-requirements#BKMK_7) documentation ports 443 (TLS) and 49443 (WAP)

Good luck!

Comment: The question is regarding network ports between Domain Controller and ADFS server. The document doesn't mention this because it considers ADFS and AD are deployed in the same network without firewall. More information, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200575/how-does-adfs-communicate-with-ad

Comment: @Cyril I would interpret the `AD servers` in question to reference AD member servers, not domain controllers. So I think the answer is valid.

Comment: @DavidTrevorD Actually the original post includs two questions: 1)"What NSG rules do I need to add to incoming and outgoing for the ADFS and AD Subnets?" 2) "Which ports need to be opened for ADFS Proxy Servers to ADFS Servers?" The first one is regarding network between AD (DC) and ADFS and the second question is regarding ADFS proxy (WAP) and ADFS.

Comment: (continue) The first one requires all the network ports for traffic between member server and DC. The second one is for WAP and ADFS and only 443 is needed. Port 49443 is for traffic between Client and WAP. Here is the related document for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/hybrid/connect/reference-connect-ports